# Locate Plone Management Interface with Plone2.5, Zope2.9.4 and python2.4.3

Tags: python, plone, zope

I have installed Plone2.5 on my system, and I'm running the server and two client's using `sudo /opt/Plone-2.5/zeocluster/bin/startcluster.sh`

With above setup and default configuration I can get the Zope's management interface at `localhost:8080/manage/`

I don't have any knowledge on Plone or Zope, But I see the Plone and Zope Interfaces differ from each other in screenshots of Plone setup.

How do I access the Plone management Interface?

Comment: Any reason to use Plone 2.5 instead of 4.3? Thought the answer would be the same, just curious

Comment: I want to add some new features to existing application developed in plone2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Plone Control Panel is located under `http://localhost:8080/$(PLONESITE)/plone_control_panel` in Plone 2.5.x.

By default the link is located in the top right corner:
[image]